# Do simple paths have unique endpoints?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a simple path.

That is there exists a continuous injective function $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the image of $f$ is $Y$.

Note, by this definition $f(0)$ cannot equal $f(1)$.

Now assume there exists another continuous injective function $g : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ whose image is also $Y$.

Can $\{f(0), f(1)\} \neq \{g(0), g(1)\}$?

Comment: Is $g^{-1}$ automatically continuous under these hypotheses? If so the problem reduces to the continuous bijection $g^{-1}\circ f$ from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, where it should be easy to establish that the image of $\{0,1\}$ is $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @GregMartin The [Closed Graph Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem#Closed_graph_theorem_in_point-set_topology) guarantees that $g$ has closed graph, and that $g^{-1}$ is therefore continuous.

Comment: Note also, @c.abate, that this proof works in any Hausdorff topological space, as any such path $Y$ is the continuous image of the compact interval $[0, 1]$, hence making $Y$ compact (and Hausdorff).

Comment: Thank you guys, I will need to do a little more research in order to fully understand your answers.

Comment: In the same spirit as the answer given; you can argue that $f(0), f(1)$ are the only two points that, when removed, don't break the connectedness of $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take ourselves through Greg's suggestion. If $g : [0, 1] \to Y \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ is injective, then it is bijective due to restricting the range. This implies $g^{-1}$ exists. We wish to show it is continuous.

Suppose $(x_n) \in Y$ is a sequence converging to $x \in Y$. Let $t_n = g^{-1}(x_n)$ for all $n$, and $t = g^{-1}(x)$. We wish to show that $t_n \to t$.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $t_n \not\to t$. Then, for some $\varepsilon > 0$, there must exist a subsequence $t_{n_k}$ such that $|t_{n_k} - t| \ge \varepsilon$. By taking further subsequences as necessary, since $[0, 1]$ is compact, we may assume that $t_{n_k} \to t'$ for some $t' \in [0, 1]$. Note that $|t' - t| \ge \varepsilon$, and so $t \neq t'$.

Since $g$ is continuous, $g(t_{n_k}) = x_{n_k} \to g(t')$. But, $x_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of the convergent sequence $x_n \to x$, and so $x_{n_k} \to x$. This implies that $x = g(t') \implies t' = g^{-1}(x) = t$. This contradicts $t' \neq t$. Thus, $g$ is continuous.

From here we see, as Greg suggests, that $h:= g^{-1} \circ f$ is a continuous, bijective map from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$.

Consider $t_0 := h^{-1}(0)$. If $t_0 \in (0, 1)$, then $t_1:= t_0 / 2 \in (0, t_0)$ and $t_2 := (1 - t_0) / 2 \in (t_0, 1)$. By injectivity, $h(t_1), h(t_2) > 0$. Pick some $s \in (0, \min\{h(t_1), h(t_2)\})$. Then $0 < s < h(t_1)$ and $0 < s < h(t_2)$. By applying intermediate value theorem twice, we can find $t_3 \in (t_1, t_0) \subseteq (0, t_0)$ and $t_4 \in (t_0, t_2) \subseteq (t_0, 1)$ such that
$$h(t_3) = h(t_4) = s,$$
despite $t_3 < t_0 < t_4$. This contradicts the intermediate value theorem. Thus, $h^{-1}(0) \in \{0, 1\}$. A similar proof shows that $h^{-1}(1) \in \{0, 1\}$ too. Injectivity of $h^{-1}$ implies that these points are different, so
$$\{h^{-1}(0), h^{-1}(1)\} = \{0, 1\}.$$
Applying the bijection $g \circ h = f$ to both sets, we get
$$\{g(0), g(1)\} = \{f(0), f(1)\}.$$

Comment: How about using $f^{-1}$? I am just a freshmen, less educated  so I cannot make a proof. But I know $f$ is simple, so it is also injective. The proof cannot be made using that?

Comment: @Nightflight I am not sure what you're thinking of here. In a way, I am indeed using the inverse curve, just using the inverse of $g$ instead of $f$. I think this is as simple as the proof will get (unless we simply remove the first four paragraphs and refer to the closed graph theorem). The structure of these simple paths are derived from the structure of $[0, 1]$, and so it is natural to expect there to be a function from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$ involved.